# Should use a stream or container when working with network, binary data and serialization

Tags: c++, networking, serialization, boost-asio

I am working on a TCP server using boost asio and I got lost with choosing the best data type to work with when dealing with byte buffers.

Currently I am using `std::vector<char>` for everything. One of the reasons is that most of examples of asio use vectors or arrays. I receive data from network and put it in a buffer vector. Once a packet is available, it is extracted from the buffer and decrypted/decompressed if needed (both operations may result in more amount of data). Then multiple messages are extracted from the payload.

I am not happy with this solution because it involves inserting and removing data from vectors constantly, but it does the job.

Now I need to work on data serialization. There is not an easy way to read or write arbitrary data types from a char vector so I ended up implementing a "buffer" that hides a vector inside, and allows to write (wrapper for insert) and read (wrapper for casting) from it. Then I can write `uint16 code; buffer >> code;` and also add serialization/deserialization methods to other objects while keeping things simple.

The thing is that every time I think about this I feel like I am using the wrong data type as container for the binary data. Reasons are:

- Streams already do a good job as potentially endless source of data input or data output. While in background this may result in inserting and removing data, probably does a better job than using a char vector.
- Streams already allow to read or write basic data types, so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.
- There is no need to access to a specific position of data. Usually I need to read or write sequentially.

In this case, are streams the best choice or is there something that I am not seeing?. And if so, is `stringstream` the one I should use?

Any reasons to avoid streams and work only with containers?

PD: I can not use boost serialization or any other existing solution because I don't have control over the network protocol.

Comment: When working with arbitrary binary data `std::vector<std::byte>` would be *my* initial go-to container. At least unless there's some really good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine. You might consider a `deque` instead of a `vector` if you're doing a *lot* of stealing from the end and erasing from the front, but if you use circular-buffer logic while iterating then this doesn't matter either.

You *could* switch to a stream, but then you're completely at the mercy of the standard library, its annoyances/oddities, and the semantics of its formatted extraction routines — if these are insufficient then you have to extract `N` bytes and do your own reinterpretation anyway, so you're back to square one but with added copying and indirection.

You say you don't need random-access, so that's another reason not to care either way. Personally I like to have random-access in case I need to resync, or seek-ahead, or seek-behind, or even just during debugging want to have better capabilities without having to suddenly refactor all my buffer code.

I don't think there's any more specific answer to this in the general case.